# Hidden Columns in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is there any way to hide a column in a jqGrid table, but have it show as read-only when the row is edited in the form editor modal dialog?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I just want to expand on **queen3**'s suggestion, applying the following does the trick:

```
editoptions: { 
              dataInit: function(element) { 
                          $(element).attr("readonly", "readonly"); 
                        } 
             }
```

**Scenario #1**:

- Field must be visible in the grid
- Field must be visible in the form
- Field must be read-only

**Solution**:

```
colModel:[
        {  name:'providerUserId',
               index:'providerUserId', 
               width:100,editable:true, 
               editrules:{required:true}, 
               editoptions:{ 
                            dataInit: function(element) { 
                                  jq(element).attr("readonly", "readonly"); 
                             } 
                           }
            },
],
```

The providerUserId is visible in the grid and visible when editing the form. But you cannot edit the contents.

---

**Scenario #2**:

- Field must not be visible in the grid
- Field must be visible in the form
- Field must be read-only

**Solution**:

```
colModel:[
           {name:'providerUserId',
            index:'providerUserId', 
            width:100,editable:true, 
            editrules:{
                         required:true, 
                         edithidden:true
                      },
            hidden:true, 
            editoptions:{ 
                  dataInit: function(element) {                     
                             jq(element).attr("readonly", "readonly"); 
                          } 
                     }
         },
        ]
```

Notice in both instances I'm using jq to reference jquery, instead of the usual $. In my HTML I have the following script to modify the variable used by jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Comment: superb explanation with scenarios..!! +1

Answer (score 81):

This feature is built into jqGrid.

setup your grid function as follows.

```
$('#myGrid').jqGrid({
   ...
   colNames: ['Manager', 'Name', 'HiddenSalary'],
   colModel: [               
               { name: 'Manager', editable: true },
               { name: 'Price', editable: true },
               { name: 'HiddenSalary', hidden: true , editable: true, 
                  editrules: {edithidden:true} 
               }
             ],
   ...
};
```

There are other editrules that can be applied but this basic setup would hide the manager's salary in the grid view but would allow editing when the edit form was displayed.

Comment: Thats almost what I'm looking for, except I don't want it to be editable in the edit form.  I'm thinking there's no way to do that.

Answer (score 25):

You can use the following code to hide a table column..

```
JQuery("tableName").hideCol("colName");
```

And you can use the following code to show it again.

```
JQuery("tableName").showCol("colName");
```

For your question, you can call the hideCol() code on the document.ready(), and you can bind the showCol() code on the dialog's edit/click event.

Comment: You'll also probably want to bind the hideCol() code in an event that corresponds to the editing being complete, or when the user/editor is doing editing.

Answer (score 7):

This thread is pretty old I suppose, but in case anyone else stumbles across this question...
I had to grab a value from the selected row of a table, but I didn't want to show the column that row was from.  I used hideCol, but had the same problem as Andy where it looked messy.  To fix it (call it a hack) I just re-set the width of the grid.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

       jQuery("#ItemGrid").jqGrid({ 
                ..., 
                width: 700,
                ...
        }).hideCol('StoreId').setGridWidth(700)
```

Since my row widths are automatic, when I reset the width of the table it reset the column widths but excluded the hidden one, so they filled in the gap.

Comment: Try [this method](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/recall-and-set-column-widths/) for resizing the columns after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use edithidden: true and also do

```
editoptions: { dataInit: function(element) { $(element).attr("readonly", "readonly"); } }
```

Or see jqGrid wiki for custom editing, you can setup any input type, even label I think.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the grid column

```
jQuery("#validGrid").jqGrid('hideCol',str);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit old, this post. But this is my code to show/hide the columns. I use the built in function to display the columns and just mark them.

Function that displays columns shown/hidden columns. The #jqGrid is the name of my grid, and the columnChooser is the jqGrid column chooser.

```
  function showHideColumns() {
        $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('columnChooser', {
            width: 250,
            dialog_opts: {
                modal: true,
                minWidth: 250,
                height: 300,
                show: 'blind',
                hide: 'explode',
                dividerLocation: 0.5
            } });
```