# jQgrid show hidden column in form view

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

```
jQuery("#CustomerDetailsGrid").jqGrid({
    //ignore other properties
    colModel: [
    { name: 'AccountNumber', index: 'AccountNumber', hidden: true, viewable: true }
],
    viewrecords: true        
});
```

I need to hide the column "Account Number" in grid view but show it in the form view.(**Not edit form**)

Comment: There's an easier way listed in another question on StackOverflow: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661800/hidden-columns-in-jqgrid)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the View dialog will be created it will be filled with the information about every column placed in the rows. The id of the row (the id of `<tr>` element) will be constructed from the prefix "trv_" and the name of the corresponding column. It it important to understand, that in the form it will be filled the information about **all** columns **inclusive hidden columns**, but `<tr>` elements for the hidden columns will be hidden (has style="display: none;"). So to make the information visible it is enough to call `jQuery.show()` function for the corresponding `<tr>` element.

I prepared [the small demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ViewHidden.htm) which demonstrate this. In the demo `id` column are hidden, but I make the information visible inside of `beforeShowForm` and `afterclickPgButtons` event handler of the View options:

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
                  {add:false,edit:false,del:false,view:true,search:false},
                  {}, // edit options
                  {}, // add options
                  {}, // del options
                  {}, // search options
                  {   // vew options
                      beforeShowForm: function(form) {
                          $("tr#trv_id",form[0]).show();
                      },
                      afterclickPgButtons: function(whichbutton, form, rowid) {
                          $("tr#trv_id",form[0]).show();
                      }
                  });
```

Comment: since the question is 2 years old, I was wondering: are there any up-to-date solutions to this? NB: JqSuite for PHP -

Comment: @JessStone: I don't use jqSuite myself, but I suppose all is the same as in jqGrid. On can use `editrules: {edithidden: true}`, but it's not pure option for View. It will be used for editing too. If you don't use editing and just want to display some hidden columns you can use `editrules: {edithidden: true}`.

Comment: Dear @Oleg, I found out I just have to use "editable" => false, since my goal is to show the column in table, and hide in the edit form. thanks anyway, you are a JqGrid GURU, I am voting up all your answers! ! :)

Comment: For unknown hidden columns, one can use : $('tr[id^="trv_"]', form[0]).show();

Answer (score 13):

The best way is only adding the editrules:{edithidden:true} option.

```
colModel: [{ name: 'AccountNumber', index: 'AccountNumber', hidden: true, viewable: true,editrules:{edithidden:true} }]
```

Answer (score 3):

To follow-up **J_**'s suggestion, applying the following does the trick:

```
editoptions: { dataInit: function(element) { $(element).attr("readonly", "readonly"); } }
```

**Scenario #1**:

- Field must be visible in the grid
- Field must be visible in the form
- Field must be read-only

**Solution**:

```
colModel:[
   {name:'providerUserId',index:'providerUserId', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{ dataInit: function(element) { jq(element).attr("readonly", "readonly"); } }},
],
```

The providerUserId is visible in the grid and visible when editing the form. But you cannot edit the contents.

---

**Scenario #2**:

- Field must not be visible in the grid
- Field must be visible in the form
- Field must be read-only

**Solution**:

```
colModel:[
    {name:'providerUserId',index:'providerUserId', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true, edithidden:true}, hidden:true, editoptions:{ dataInit: function(element) { jq(element).attr("readonly", "readonly"); } }},
]
```

Notice in both instances I'm using jq to reference jquery, instead of the usual $. In my HTML I have the following script to modify the variable used by jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide the grid column

```
jQuery("#GridId").jqGrid('hideCol','colName');
```