# Jqgrid view records allows editable fields editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using **Jqgrid version 4.4.0.** My grid is little complex grid with inline editing.
on select of row I make row editable based on condition. 
Below is the code for making row editable.

```
$("#list1").jqGrid('editRow', id, true, null,null,null,null, successfunc );
```

In the grid's navbutton I have "View record" button. On click of view button, View form shows all the field. View records gives option to edit editable fields. I want to restrict user view only here rather editing. When I searched jqgrid wiki it shows no Events are associated with this "View Records" button. I also tried to customize using beforeShowForm: `function(formid){}`. But no luck. Please suggest how to achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events1) with "View" button from the navigator button. See examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4651561/315935) for example.

Moreover I would recommend you to use parameters of [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) in object form:

```
$("#list1").jqGrid('editRow', id, {
    keys: true,
    successfunc: successfunc
});
```

It makes the code more readable in my opinion because one don't need cont the position of every parameter.