# JQgrid Editing Form reload

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there a way to refresh the edit form dialog to apply updated options on the grid made on the fly?
Basically I need to change some properties when a dropdownlist value has changed, and then the dialog reflect those changes. For example, I update the property editable to hide a field.

```
container.jqGrid('setColProp', fieldName, { editable: false});
```

Is there any way to that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the column data in the postback sent when the grid is loaded. Set the url with the url property:

```
url: $("#BlendGrades").jqGrid({
    url: '/Storage/GreenStorage/SetSectionList?q=2&location.Id=' + '<%:Model.Location.Id%>',
    datatype: "json", .....
```

Comment: I don't want to make a request to the server.
In the edit form dialog when the user change a dropdownlist value some fields have to disappear and anothers have to appear and i make that using that line of code but the dialog form has to be reload with the new settings

Comment: Then you can use the  afterclickPgButtons option see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645787/jqgrid-show-hidden-column-in-form-view/4651561#4651561