# Jqgrid - hidden columns does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

My colmodel definition looks like follows:

```
<c name='NewShippingAddressCity' index='NewShippingAddressCity' align='left' sortable='false' hidden='true' width='150'></c>
```

but I don't know why this column is still visible. What should I change to hide it?

I use jqgrid 4.4.0

EDIT 1
It looks like from some reaseon hidden attribute becomes 'undefined' so te javascript sets it to false instead of true.

Answer (score 1):

No by default value of hidden is false. try to give it with out quotes and as i can not check your entire code, follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661800/hidden-columns-in-jqgrid)  there are plenty of methods in answers which can provide you the functionality.

Alternatively, you can use hideCol property of jqgrid. See the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods)